# Error in upadating ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I was trying to update my Ubuntu 14.04 system using terminal but I got this result

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
```

Also in the top-right corner of my PC there is a red triangle which says the update information is outdated. Again when I tried to download something from software repository there comes a window which says untrusted package ,then when I select ok then another window pops out which says check your Internet connection. But I am well connected to the Internet(under proxy network),so what should I do?

Comment: There's something that you need to do to allow `apt-get` through the proxy, but I'm not sure what. You could also just disconnect from the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In a terminal, run this command:  sudo apt-get update

Then run this command:  sudo apt-get autoclean

Then run this command:  sudo apt full-upgrade

If that doesn't work, a fresh install may be easier than extensive troubleshooting, after backing up your personal data.

I hope this helps.

RCline7